# guardar tabla html en bd usando jsf o jsp

Tags: java, jsf, jsp

Tengo una tabla HTML dinámica

```
<TABLE>
<TR>
    <TD align="center">ID Interno</TD>
    <TD align="center">UID Externo</TD>
    <TD align="center">ID Interno</TD>
    <TD align="center">UID Externo</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
    <TD><input type="text"/></TD>
    <TD><input type="text"/></TD>
    <TD><input type="text"/></TD>
    <TD><input type="text"/></TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
```

Quiero recorrerla y guardar el contenido de sus líneas rellenadas manualmente en una base de datos. Estoy haciendo una aplicación web en JAVA y quiero preguntar si alguien me puede ayudar en cómo hacerlo usando JSF o JSP.

Comment: Desde JSF 2, se recomienda preferir Facelets sobre JSP como tecnología para la vista. Te diría que indiques con cuál de estos frameworks trabajas para proveer una solución.

Answer (score 1):

Si modificas el siguiente ejemplo tendrás lo que necessitas.

```
 <html>
 <head><title>Enter to database</title></head>
 <body>
 <table>
 <%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
 <%@ page import="javax.sql.*;" %>
 <% 

 java.sql.Connection con;
 java.sql.Statement s;
 java.sql.ResultSet rs;
 java.sql.PreparedStatement pst;

 con=null;
 s=null;
 pst=null;
 rs=null;

 // Remember to change the next line with your own environment
 String url= 
 "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://nameofyourdatabaseserver.or.ipaddress/yourdatabasename";
 String id= "username";
 String pass = "password";
 try{

      Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
      con = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(url, id, pass);

 }catch(ClassNotFoundException cnfex){
      cnfex.printStackTrace();

 }
 String sql = "select top 10 * from tbl_sys_user";
 try{
      s = con.createStatement();
      rs = s.executeQuery(sql);
 %>

 <%
 while( rs.next() ){
 %><tr>
 <td><%= rs.getString("cust_id") %></td>
 <td><%= rs.getString("rdate") %></td>
 <td><%= rs.getString("email") %></td>
 </tr>
 <%
 }
 %>

 <%

 }
 catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
 finally{
      if(rs!=null) rs.close();
      if(s!=null) s.close();
      if(con!=null) con.close();
 }

 %>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Gracias Victor por tu respuesta, pero eso es sacar datos de la base de datos y desplegarlos en la tabla HTML no ?!! yo lo quiero al reves.